# MySQL, PHP: echo IDs from smalest to largest

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple code in PHP and actual code throws all items from MySQL table with even ID and under it all items with odd ID.

And I need to all IDs with content will be listed from smallest to largest under themselves.

```
if( $db-> connect_error ) {
    die( "Not connected" . $db-> connect_error );
}

$sqlEven = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE MOD (id,2)=0";
$resultEven = $db-> query($sqlEven);

if( $resultEven-> num_rows ) {
    while( $rowEven = $resultEven-> fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo $rowEven["id"] . "<li class=\"dark\"><a href=\"" . $rowEven["url"] . "\">" . $rowEven["name"] . "</a></li>";
    }
}

if( $db-> connect_error ) {
    die( "Not connected" . $db-> connect_error );
}

$sqlOdd = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE MOD (id,2)<>0";
$resultOdd = $db-> query($sqlOdd);

if( $resultOdd-> num_rows ) {
    while( $rowOdd = $resultOdd-> fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo $rowOdd["id"] . "<li class=\"light\"><a href=\"" . $rowOdd["url"] . "\">" . $rowOdd["name"] . "</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want an `ORDER BY id`?

Comment: Yes but I need leave similar structure, when PHP echo it to even will have class="dark" and odd have class="light"

Comment: You could even `ORDER BY MOD (id,2), id`

Comment: and where it can be?

Comment: i cant add it to existng MySQL commands

Comment: @NigelRen Can do `ORDER BY id`, the modulus isn't needed in the order. If you order by `2, 4, 6` or  `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` doesn't matter :-)

Comment: @Qirel ordering by the MOD would mean you could do it in 1 statement rather than 2.

Comment: but  need when PHP echo it to even will have class="dark" and odd have class="light", that is it what I need

Comment: @NigelRen Ah, of course - if you want a single query. Clever.

Comment: please help me how to do t m lost

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this to one query and check in PHP if the number is even or odd. Using a ternary operator, it can be done inline. Using `ORDER BY MOD(id, 2), id` (sort by even first, then ascending order), you get the data sorted by even and odd (see live fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af25e5/2).

This way, you only need one query and one loop.

```php
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Not connected: " . $db->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM documents ORDER BY MOD(id, 2), id";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["id"] . '<li class="'.($row['id'] % 2 == 0 ? 'dark' : 'light').'"><a href="'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["name"]."</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: it is still not ordered from smallest to largest ID sorry for my roughness

Comment: but  meant somethng lke 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 no 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5

Comment: Then use `ORDER BY MOD(id, 2) = 0, id`